# how to migrate a gupta (SQLBase) database to MySQL (including data)

Tags: mariadb, database-migration, guptateamdeveloper

Im trying to migrate a Gupta DB to MySQL. I already have a script to create every Table (with indexes and comments) and views I need in MySQL (table-, view- and column-names as well as column-types are equal in gupta as well as MySQL). But now I cant figure out how to read data from the old SQLBase Database and "import it" into the new MySQL database.

i thought of reading the old data from SQLBase and writing it in a file to then read it somehow via MySQL to import it. the Problem here is that for some tables there are more than 1 million records which i can not lose a single one of....

Comment: MYSQL <> MARIADB

Comment: Export your data from GuptaDB to CSV file then import it into MySQL.

Comment: but i can work with MySQL in MariaDB

Comment: *but i can work with MySQL in MariaDB* No. You can work with MySQL in MySQL or with MariaDB in MariaDB only.

Comment: PS. On MySQL - remove foreign keys before importing if exists, you'd recreate them after.

Comment: mariadb started as a fork of mysql  which shares many mysql features but it's not a drop in replacement.

Comment: okay thank you. so what SQL script type do i need to work with mariadb if not MySQL?

Comment: There are tons of ETL (extract-transform-load) tools out there that can connect to both databases and perform the migration. Also, you can check with various control totals if the migration was successful.

Comment: do you have a good (and free) recommendation for such an ETL tool that would work with outdated gupta?

Comment: Asking for and providing product recommendations are explicitly off topic here on SO.

Comment: Firstly, the very popular Gupta database is **'SQLBase'** not 'BaseSQL'.  
Secondly, your opinion of 'outdated' Gupta is completely unfounded, of topic and you should keep your opinions to yourself - they are damaging , untrue, and potentially erode those many sites that do actually rely on the a very reliable and modern SQLBase.    Thirdly, if you'd done proper research on SO, you'd see that you can happily ETL from SQLBase natively - see my answer below.  p.s. for those who don't understand, you can learn about the 'real' SQLBase here: https://www.opentext.com/products/gupta-sqlbase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ETL natively from Gupta 'SQLBase' very easily. But you need to read the manual appropriate for your SQLBase version here:  [Gupta SQLBase manuals ( all verions )](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/) , specifically, you need to read the 'UNLOAD' command in the 'Language Reference' manual.  But best advice is: Don't do it ! Upgrade to SQLBase v12.2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

We also use SQLBase in various versions, including 12.2. We too are considering a switch to MySQL, MariaDB, or Microsoft SQL Server. We're quite bothered by the fact that SQLBase still doesn't offer Entity Framework support. This means that one has to either directly access the database via Team Developer or use ADO.NET when programming in C#.

The issue is that we have a significant amount of code in Team Developer 7.5, so we can't simply swap out the database. Specifically, we no longer want to develop using ADO.NET but with Entity Framework instead.

What needs to be done so we can use a different database like MySQL, MariaDB, Postgre, or MS SQL Server with Team Developer 7.5? This way, we could finally access the database from .NET using Entity Framework, while still leveraging the existing Team Developer code.